# Multiselect attribute not showing on frontend when two or more options selected

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, custom-attributes

I have a custom product attribute that uses a multiselect input to select one or more product stockists.

The data is being stored correctly, and selecting 1 option adds the information to the "More information' tab on the product frontend page.

Selecting 2 or more options, the information is no longer visible on the frontend.

Attribute config below

```
$eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                'stockist',
                [
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'label' => 'Stockist',
                    'input' => 'multiselect',
                    'source' => 'My\Module\Model\Attribute\Source\Stockist',
                    'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                    'visible' => true,
                    'required' => false,
                    'searchable' => true,
                    'filterable' => true,
                    'comparable' => false,
                    'visible_on_front' => true,
                    'used_in_product_listing' => true
                ]
            );
```

My\Module\Model\Attribute\Source\Stockist:

```
namespace My\Module\Model\Attribute\Source;

use My\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Stockist\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource;

class Stockist extends AbstractSource
{
    private $collectionFactory;

    public function __construct(CollectionFactory $collectionFactory)
    {
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    }

    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $stockistCollection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
        $stockistCollection->addFieldToSelect('*')->load();

        $result = [];

        foreach ($stockistCollection as $stockist) {
            $result[] = [
                'value' => $stockist->getId(),
                'label' => $stockist->getName()
            ];
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you select more then one options, does it save sucessfully into database?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya yes it does, it saves as a comma separated list of IDs

Comment: how does your My\Module\Model\Attribute\Source\Stockist look like?

Comment: @HelgeB updated my question.

Comment: OK, do you know how you access the data in Frontend? do you use `$product->getAttributeText()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this method to your `Stockist` class:

```
public function getOptionText($value)
{
    $isMultiple = false;
    if (strpos($value, ',')) {
        $isMultiple = true;
        $value = explode(',', $value);
    }

    $options = $this->getAllOptions();

    if (!is_array($value)) {
        $value = [$value];
    }
    $optionsText = [];
    foreach ($options as $item) {
        if (in_array($item['value'], $value)) {
            $optionsText[] = $item['label'];
        }
    }

    if ($isMultiple) {
        return $optionsText;
    } elseif ($optionsText) {
        return $optionsText[0];
    }

    return false;
}
```

haven't tested it, so watch out for typos and syntax errors.

Off topic things but might help.
You don't need to reload from the db all data each time `getAllOptions` is called:

```
class Stockist extends AbstractSource
{
    private $collectionFactory;
    $private $options;

    public function __construct(CollectionFactory $collectionFactory)
    {
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    }

    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        if ($this->options === null) {
            $stockistCollection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
            $stockistCollection->addFieldToSelect('*')->load();

            $this->options = [];

            foreach ($stockistCollection as $stockist) {
                $this->options[] = [
                    'value' => $stockist->getId(),
                    'label' => $stockist->getName()
                ];
            }
        }
        return $this->options;
    }
}
```

Comment: That works great, thank you! Any idea how to get it working with the search and filters? They are set to true in my config, but I assume I'm missing some other methods in my Attribute source model?

Comment: Do you have Flat Catalog option as enabled?

Comment: @PaulCanning It should work if you set it as "used_in_layered_navigation" and "used_in_search"

Comment: I have only `searchable` set to `true` - which I assumed would be enough. Is there documentation as to what attribute options are available?

Comment: Adding `'used_in_search' => true` in the attribute options works, but only when I have one option selected. 2 or more options and they do not get added to the `catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1` table

Comment: @PaulCanning did you manage to make it filtrable when two or more values are selected? :)

Comment: @RobertSchmidt i'll have to go back and take a look. Can't remember off the top of my head if i did or not.

Comment: @PaulCanning I would very much appreciate it if you find the time. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much @Marius. That works great!